# Existe alguna manera simple de convertir una lista de tipo str a una de tipo int?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

Tengo un archivo .csv en el cual en una columna 'Nivel' donde hay datos tipo str me gustaría cambiar cada dato por un número, por ejemplo:

```
df1['Level'] = pd.to_int(df1['Level'])
Bajo = 1
Medio =2
Alto = 3
```

No encuentro la manera de hacerlo con pandas, de esta manera no me ha funcionado.

> df1['Level'] = pd.to_int(df1['Level'])

Answer (score 0):

Puedes emplear la función `astype` para convertir el tipo de los valores.

```
df['Level'] = df['Level'].astype(int)
```

Te dejo por aca la documentación [astype pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)